# Microsoft Access VBA - IF statement always evaluates Else expression

Tags: database, ms-access, if-statement, vba

I want to construct an `if` statement using some text as a condition.

In my field `Status_anggota` there is a combobox that has either `"Active"` or `"Not active"` as its value.

My problem is that it won't get the value of of the `"Active"` and so it only shows the false statement:

```vb
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select Status_anggota from Tbl_anggota Where Kode_anggota='" & Text2 & "'")
If rs.RecordCount = "Active" Then
    MsgBox "Status is active", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Status is not active", vbInformation
End If
```

Comment: RecordCount is a _number_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inspecting the value held by a single field within a single record with no iteration, it is usually simpler to use the [`DLookup`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) function, e.g.:

```vb
If DLookup("Status_anggota", "Tbl_anggota", "Kode_anggota='" & Text2 & "'") = "Active" Then
    MsgBox "Status is active", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Status is not active", vbInformation
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select Status_anggota from Tbl_anggota Where Kode_anggota='" & Text2 & "'")

If rs!Status_anggota.Value = "Active" Then
    MsgBox "Status is active", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Status is not active", vbInformation
End If
```